# How can I put the codes of a jssor-slider in a block on a drupal 8 page?

Tags: drupal-8, jssor

I've created a jssor-slider that I want to place in the second featured bottom block in Drupal 8.

In which file should I add the code of the slider and in which folder do I find this file?

Comment: Hi Kofi! Could you provide us with your already existing file structure or some more examples to better understand your problem?

Comment: Hi Karlisup! Many thanks for your help. The slide works well as stand-alone. But I don't know how  (or where) to put the code in which file and in which file structure of my Drupal 8 website in construction. The code is as follows:

Comment: Opps! it is impossible to send the whole code of the slider! But the file structures look as follows: drupal/htdocs/sites/default/files

Comment: and drupal/htdocs/core/themes/bartik/